# where to configure phpstorm 7 less compile directory

Tags: less, phpstorm

I'm using Phpstorm7 on mac. When I open one less file, Phpstorm tells me that it can be watched, so I just allow it to be watched. However, I want to compile this less file to another directory, instead of the same directory.

Saying, I need compile sites/all/themes/bic/less/style.less to sites/all/themes/css/style.css.

After a long research, it seems I need to edit some file watcher, but I can't find such file watcher stuff anywehre in Phpstorm7. There's no such 'File watcher' setting when I go to 'File' => 'Default Settings' in Phpstorm7. Now I can't stop this less from compiling either.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`File | Default Settings` is for settings that will be applied to the **brand new projects**.

All settings (both IDE-wide as well as project specific) are located **in the same place as every other Mac program does** -- it's called **"Preferences"** (which you should now where to find, since you are a Mac user).

---

PhpStorm v7.x  has a feature called *Search Everywhere* (<kbd>Shift</kbd> 2 times or by clicking on corresponding icon in toolbar) -- it searches trough settings/preferences as well.

Comment: Thanks! Shift 2 times and then searching 'watcher' will open Project Settings "File Watchers" where I can edit and add file watchers!